# when InstallShield 2011 premier integrated in VS2010 .NET dependencies are not added at build time

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, dependencies, installshield-2011

I have added an IS2011 project to my existing VS2010 solution. My VS solution
contains several projects. I have added the primary output of the main project
to IS2011. When the IS2011 project builds it sometimes adds the .NET dependencies and 
sometimes gives warning that cannot find the dependencies. 
it produces build warning 6248. I spent a lot of time searching for this problem and found the following link on flexera software website but it wasn't helpful at all as it suggests that the dlls have been moved or deleted!! which is not the case for me.

http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q107276

It even sometimes 
looks for strange dependencies like "a.tmp" or ".dll" and gives warning that
it cannot find them either!
I don't understand why it behaves like that? anyone has encountered the same problem?
what is the solution? Adding the dependencies manually?!!

Please bear in mind that I also have a VS setup installer project that picks up all the dependencies automatically and has no problem. But why IS cannot do that?

Answer (score 0):

the built-in IS2011 from VS2010 is Limited Edition..
unfortunately, This edition cannot use any dependencies from your project..

the only solution is subscribing for Express Edition or Professional Edition OR use the ordinary VS Setup Project.